# Show Alert using tooltip in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a small application in which I need to show alerts if a particular condition is met. I have an mdi form and several child forms. Now the best way to show an alert is to show a tooltip on the right side corner of my mdi form. Though this works, but the problem is I want user to close the tooltip once he has read.

Now the tooltip that vb.net provide does not support click events. If I give a long time duration the tooltip would be open all the time and if I give a short duration then it will close quickly.

What can I do ?

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

GR

Comment: Tooltip? Are you using WinForms or WebForms?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider a statusbar at the bottom of the window instead of a tooltip (like at the bottom of Word). You can intercept clicks on those, split the bar into several sections as necessary, etc.

Alternately, I'd probably code up a little pop up form with no border, min/max.close buttons etc, like a toast message, and show it as necessary, Stick an RTF control on it and you're "tooltips" can be very richly formatted, add a timer and the window can disappear after a short timeout, or intecept the click and close it manually.

Comment: Creating a borderless form may not work out if I make it an mdi child. This will cause form to maximize if any mdi child form is maximized at that point. If its a normal form it will stick out if the main form is moved.